# 3D model is partially black in texture mode

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I created a 3D figure and after I wanted to see how a texture applies to it I found out that it looks partially black, but cannot figure out why. I tried recalculating normals, but it didn't help. Can someone please help me?

[image]

[image: Object mode view]

Comment: can you provide the blend file?

Comment: Sorry, I have added it now :)

Comment: It seems that when I move the lamp object gets illuminated on parts where the lamp is just properly, but this never happened to me before that I would have to move the lamp around to see if everything is ok, so I have no idea what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem. You are using Blender Render instead of Blender Cycles. If you want to continue to use Blender Render, you just need to add a new light source to iluminate that side. It is just a hard shadow! You can add a sun, and rotate it to be horizontal ilumination, as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but I'm just wondering how did this happen? I never had to do it before when working on 3D models... I just have a problem with this one and I always used blender render... Whole objects got illuminated just fine..

Comment: maybe it was the position of the light. In this case, your lights were at right of the object, causing shadow on left.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I had to delete the lamp and object turned bright as I wanted immediately :) Just to let people that might be asking the same question know...